# IP add route doesn't work

Tags: linux, ip, routes

I have 3 virtual machines:

lab1:
eth1 172.16.1.5
eth2 172.16.2.6

lab2:
eth1:172.16.1.7

lab3:
eth1:172.16.2.8

Now I want add route in lab3 so that it can reach lab2 via lab1 . My command is  `sudo ip route add 172.16.1.0/24 via 172.16.2.6` , and my route table in lab3 is like this:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         lab1            0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
default         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
172.16.1.0      lab1            255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1
172.16.2.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.8.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

However, I cant reach lab2, but when I ping lab1, it worked. Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score -1):

172.16.1.0      lab1            255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1
172.16.2.0       *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1

These are two different networks , they cannot be on the same interface.

Answer (score -1):

You have to check routing tables on lab1 and lab2 as well.
May be you should add route entry for lab3 on lab2.
Or there may be some firewall-related issues.

Also, your entry for 172.16.1.0/24 via 172.16.2.6 is not necessary, it will be accessible via default route unless your second default route entry (which looks somewhat strange to me) will be used.